# How do I charge an AGM battery?

Tags: battery, charging

Not a one that's completely dead, but say an AGM battery that's at 75% and I want to top it off before trying to use it again.  Can I use a regular lead acid battery charger?  Do I have to worry about if the charger has a desulfation circuit (which they ALL seem to now, I couldn't find one without, I know they're death to Li-Po batteries)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the desulfation circuit, although there are mixed reviews about how effective they are.

However, AGMs are more sensitive to overcharging than a standard SLA (sealed lead-acid) batteries.  Actually, it's not the main charging cycle that is harmful, but the float-charge cycle that is used to top them off.  If you are getting a new charger, make sure it has a setting for AGM batteries.

More detailed information can be found [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/absorbent_glass_mat_agm).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

AGMs only charge to 12.8 volts. Most lead acid battery chargers go to 13.5 Volts. This will damage an AGM battery. You need a charge controller that allows you to control the maximum level.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense as that means you couldn't use an AGM in any standard car as they charge at 14 volts...

Comment: According to Australian 4WD Action magazine the answer is to use a DC to DC convertor that matches voltage to the battery type. It has the advantage that you can add solar panels later as well.